# Default time zone is not changing in php.info when we changed php.ini

Tags: php

```
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = Europe/Amsterdam
```

above is the `php.ini` config where we changed date.timezone to Europe/Amsterdam and restarted Nginx and Php-fpm still we cannot see the updated timezone in phpinfo page. only master and local values getting updated but not default timezone.

attached are the references for both php.ini and phpinfo

[image]

Comment: Did you restart the webserver after updating php.ini?

Comment: Did you edit the correct php.ini file (for your webserver)?

Comment: Yes I have restarted both Nginx and php-fpm